# select distinct with for and insert in a plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I need to make this tiny function but it doesnt work. It doesnt give me any errors only doesnt do what i need.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION relleno_masivo() returns void as 
$$
    DECLARE
r sw%rowtype;
nombre text;
BEGIN
    for r in select distinct institucion from sw where fuente='FFMM'
    LOOP
    nombre:= r.institucion;
    PERFORM * FROM inserta_mas_transadas(nombre);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

The problem is that doesnt insert anything!
thanks very much!

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Postgresql?

Comment: I removed the `sql-server` tag as this is clearly for Postgres

Comment: What do you expect the function to do? And what does `inserta_mas_transadas()` do?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a simple `insert into some_target_table (nr) select distinct institucion from sw where fuente='FFMM';`?

Comment: You'd have to say what you need and what happens. Perhaps share the code for `inserta_mas_transadas`.

Comment: @jarlh Postgresql my friend

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the function inserta_mas_transadas insert in a table, but it has to do for over 300 differents process, that s why select distinct will help to do it.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i need to make over 300 function results 's insertions in a table, but it doesnt insert anything!

Comment: That's too little information. Without a concrete example, it is guesswork.

Comment: The problem is in the undisclosed function `inserta_mas_transadas()` most likely. The question is going nowhere as it stands.